# Dúvidas em relação a uso das funções memset e memcpy

Tags: c

Eu andei fuçando alguns códigos na internet e em um certo momento acabei me deparando com as funções `memset` e `memcpy`. Eu consegui entender superficialmente o funcionamento das funções citadas, pois todas as fontes que disponibilizam alguma informação ou código de exemplo em relação a essas duas função eram de certo modo parecidas e tinham informações bastantes básicas. Contudo, acabei formulando as seguintes dúvidas:

- É errado usar `memcpy` e `memset` com dados não char?
- Qual a utilidade do ponteiro do tipo void retornado pela função `memset`?
- Qual a utilidade do ponteiro do tipo void retornado pela função `memcpy`?
- `memcpy` faz copia somente dos dados ou também ela faz a cópia do endereço do bloco copiado?

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 10
#define NEW_SIZE 20

int main(void){

    int *numbers=(int*)calloc(SIZE, sizeof(int));

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){

        numbers[i]=i+1;
    }

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){

        printf("numbers[%d]=%d\n", i, numbers[i]);
    }

    printf("\n==================\n\n");

    int *aux=(int*)realloc(numbers, NEW_SIZE*sizeof(int));

    if(aux!=NULL){

        memcpy(numbers, aux, NEW_SIZE*sizeof(int)); //isso é a mesma coisa que 'numbers=aux;' ???

        for(unsigned int i=SIZE; i<NEW_SIZE; i++){

            numbers[i]=i+1;
        }

        for(unsigned int i=0; i<NEW_SIZE; i++){

            printf("numbers[%d]=%d\n", i, numbers[i]);
        }
    }

    free(numbers);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> É errado usar `memcpy` e `memset` com dados não `char`?

- `memcpy` pode ser aplicado em qualquer tipo
- `memset` é de facto errado outra coisa com tamanho diferente de `char`. Nesse caso não irá dar o resultado pretendido, uma vez que o valor é atribuído `byte` a `byte` e interpretado como `unsigned char`.

  Da [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/):

  > (...) specified value (interpreted as an unsigned char).

  Mas é relativamente fácil de demonstrar que corre mal quando utilizado com outros tipos. Considere  o seguinte exemplo, que tenta atribuir o valor `5` a duas casas de um array de inteiros com `memset`:

  ```
  int arr[2];
  memset(arr, 5, sizeof(int) * 2);
  printf("%d %d", arr[0], arr[1]);
  ```

  Aqui poderia estar a pensar que o resultado seria `5 5` quando na verdade é:

  ```
  84215045 84215045
  ```

  [Veja no Ideone](https://ideone.com/zdfQgC)

  Mas como é que aquele resultado foi gerado ?

  Acontece que o `memset` atribuiu `5` a cada byte dos dois inteiros. Então um desses inteiros na sua representação na memoria ficou assim:

  ```
  -----------------
  | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
  -----------------
  ```

  Que expandido para binário seria assim:

  ```
  ---------------------------------------------
  | 00000101 | 00000101 | 00000101 | 00000101 |
  ---------------------------------------------
  ```

  Que forma o valor `00000101000001010000010100000101` em binário, correspondente a `84215045`.

  Quando se pretendia que tivesse ficado assim

  ```
  -----------------
  |       5       |
  -----------------
  ```

  Que expandindo também para binário já ficaria assim (assumindo o formato *little-endian*):

  ```
  ---------------------------------------------
  | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00000101 |
  ---------------------------------------------
  ```

  Este é o problema de usar tipos diferentes em `memset`. Curiosamente se quisesse atribuir `0` iria funcionar corretamente, pois `0` é sempre `0` independentemente da quantidade de bits que estamos a considerar.

> Qual a utilidade do ponteiro do tipo void retornado pela função `memset`?

Muito pouca utilidade tem este ponteiro, mas consegue por exemplo encadear chamadas de funções:

```
strcpy(memset(ptr, 0, 200), "texto");
```

Algo que não seria possivel de fazer se o tipo de retorno fosse `void`. Ainda assim é um caso bem particular e certamente incomum.

> Qual a utilidade do ponteiro do tipo void retornado pela função `memcpy`?

Mesma resposta que a questão anterior, encadear chamadas.

> `memcpy` faz copia somente dos dados ou também ela faz a cópia do endereço do bloco copiado?

`memcpy` copia somente os dados que estão no endereço passado como segundo parâmetro, chamado `source`, para o ponteiro de destino chamado `destination`.